# Django Send Email form, how to add value from another model established via foreign key

Tags: python, django, field

I am trying to create a Ticket form which sends Email. Everything is working fine, but there is a foreign key field, I am pulling data from it in this ticket, I am not able to include that in the email body.

**views.py**

```
def createTicket(request):
form = TicketForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = "Ticket Email"
        body = {
            'customer': form.cleaned_data.get('customer'),
            'subject': form.cleaned_data.get('subject'),
            'priority': form.cleaned_data.get('priority'),
            'details': form.cleaned_data.get('details'),
        }
        message = "\n".join(body.values())
        form.save()
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, 'from_email', [form.cleaned_data.get('technician_email')])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid Header')
        return redirect('/')
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'ticket_form.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
PRIORITY = (
    ('normal', 'Normal'),
    ('urgent', 'Urgent')
)
STATUS = (
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
    ('hold', 'Hold'),
    ('closed', 'Closed')
)
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
technician = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
technician_email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
priority = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, choices=PRIORITY)
details = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
Customer_type = models.ManyToManyField(Customertype, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)
```

Now the foreignkey fiend "customer", I am unable to obtain data, what is the correct method to pull value from this field. I am getting below error:

Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
sequence item 0: expected str instance, Customer found

Please help

**TRACEBACK ERROR:**

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/create_ticket/

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
 'django_filters',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'datetimewidget',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\development\website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\development\website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\development\website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\development\demo\accounts\decorators.py", line 21, in wrapper_function
    return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\development\demo\accounts\views.py", line 259, in createTicket
    message = "\n".join(body.values())

Exception Type: TypeError at /create_ticket/
Exception Value: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback?

Comment: `form.cleaned_data.get('customer')` will return a Customer object. But later you force it's string representation with `body.values()`.

Comment: I mean Share full traceback.

Comment: @SunderamDubey, I have Updated my Question with TRACEBACK ERROR.

Comment: @Marco, Can you tell me how ?

Comment: Since I don't have no idea what you expect in your message, the easiest thing would be to use a default value with `.get()` as one of your elements is None. E.g. `form.cleaned_data.get('customer', '')`